# To update particular like label of particular row in UItableview:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRzXh.png)In given screen shot i am getting this data from webservice whish is giving me 2 ID i.e.  &   which i had assigned  as a tag of follow button  and    as tag of like button & claimID + 1 as a tag of like label showing count of likes but problem occurs when i want to update count of like in label on like button click as i had assigned +1 of claimID it creates problem when that ID is really someone claimID e.g. 111 is claimID & when 112(claimID + 1) and assign tag to UIlabel than application crashes because 112 is next claimID…pls help me[image]

Comment: where is ur given screenshot ? please edit ur post :)

Comment: sory actually stackoverflow didnt allowed me to post image bcoz of reputation :(

Comment: upload the image to a web server if you can. then post the URL :)

Comment: can i mail that screen shot to u...if yes than provide me ur ID plz

Comment: now you upload your screen shots....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of +1 as a tag why dont you assign tags in multiples of 10 or 100.Eg claimId = 111 then set your button tag as claimId * 10 ie 111 * 10 = 1110 ,and so on. This way u can get rid of the tag problems.Further retrieving the claim Id is easy..[button.tag/10] shall give u your claimId back

Comment: that i had already done but can we use character with tag or only integer is allowed?